# Missing award bounty button?

Tags: discussion

trying to give a bounty to a really helpful answer (was not me who asked the question), but cannot find a button to give a bounty as stated [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties):

How do I award the bounty?

You can award a bounty by clicking on the respective button below the upvote/downvote interface.

Comment: Can you show what thread you are talking about?

Comment: Sure! http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/how-to-list-feature-classes-with-active-attribute-domains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, bounties are started on questions:

Click on the "start button" beneath "add comment" which is placed under the question (not under the answers).
Then, chose the reason you are starting a bounty on the thread. If you want to award a bounty for one of the answers you have liked, choose the following option:

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty

Then, you need to wait at least [24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer) to award the bounty to the answer you want.

However, @whuber's recommend (and I strongly agree) one wait until the grace period (8th day) to award the bounty; due to the reasons below cited.

Comment: Thanks Andre, found it!

Comment: +1 You can actually award the bounty early if you like, after a two day wait.  It's usually better not to do that: the presence of the bounty may attract more viewers who can further upvote the answer you are trying to reward, thereby returning even more for your investment.  For this to work it really helps to mention the exemplary answer when you create the bounty!